# Failing to produce a simple output with nix and perl

Tags: nix, build-tools

I'm using this script:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $output_file= %ENV{'out'};
open( my $out, ">", $output_file)
  or die "No se puede abrir $output_file: $!";
print $out %ENV;
close $out;
```

witn this nix derivation:

```hs
d = derivation { name = "dot.env"; builder = "${perl}/bin/perl" ; args=[ ejemplos/nix/env.pl ]; system = "x86_64-linux"; }
```

However, buiding that derivation (with `:b d`) fails repeatedly, producing only a `.lock` in the store directory. Even if I delete the lock file, it still fails. Any idea?

Comment: Feels to me this is not the whole story?  I mean, what creates a `.lock` file?  Not that simple code, or my Perl is too rusty  :-)

Comment: @lizmat actually, it's nix what does that. But maybe I should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

1. %ENV{'out'} will produce key/value slice. Will work in your example, but correct variant is $ENV{'out'}. `use warnings` enabled, so you can read about wrong sigil in STDERR.
2. `print $out %ENV;` is bad idea, because it will produce messy output with concatenated keys and values in random order for each execution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

%ENV = ( foo => 1, bar => 2, baz => 3 );
open (my $fh, '>', './2') or die $!;
print $fh %ENV;

# 1st run
# bar2baz3foo1
# second
# foo1bar2baz3
# third
# bar2foo1baz3
```

You can also check `close()` for errors. Not all errors can be handled after open, example:

```
perl -E'open ( my $fh, ">", "/dev/full" ) or die "No error?"; print $fh "123"; close($fh) or die $!'
```

Comment: I actually want to print the whole environment. %ENV contains the environment variables.

Comment: More human-readable solution can be: use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%ENV;

Comment: really grateful for your effort, but that's not really the problem. The problem is that it's producing no output whatsoever, but a `nix` error.